# Почему столпотворение так похоже на толпу?

Tags: этимология

Архаическое слово **столпотворение** происходит, насколько я знаю, из легенды о Вавилонской башне, т.е. *творении столпа*. Почему же так явственно звучит для нашего уха корень "толпа" - это случайное совпадение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Случайное. Слова не родственны.

Answer (score -2):

Не случайное . Стол столб - деревянное сооружение около которого предполгалось место сбора -у столба  - толпа. У греков демос-кратос у нас бы было толпо-властие.
Или возможно  на  финикийском  С ( самех )  буква обозначающая столб(п). У скотоводов это место привязки скота . Под деревом позже переделываемые в деревянные столбы-кумиры собирались люди. Лат. ТаБуЛа - доска . Толкаться у столба у стола толочь. Латыш. stabu - cтолбовая . С редуцируется и столп дает начало толпе .

Comment: Это вам так кажется? Вы смысл слов по ассоциации ищете?
Приведите примерный исторический порядок перехода одного в другое.

Поставила минус за бездоказательность.